# Visual Studio 2010 + .Net Framework 1.1 + Click Once Deployment

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2010

First of all, The Winform application is based on .Net Framework 1.1. I have 1.1 SDK installed but 1.1 is not listed in the Target Framework(VS 2010 Beta 2) so I cannot choose the same, the minimal available is 2.0. Am I supposed to install an add-on or something for building 1.1 apps in VS 2010 beta2. Further more, I am using a Clickonce deployment publish method. I am not sure if 1.1 supports ClickOnce deployment. Please advise on both these fronts.  Thanks a Lot

Comment: Yes there is a reason, the clients are far greater in number for a framework upgrade, hence we will have to stick with 1.1 for the time being

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET 1.x is not supported by VS2010 (or any future versions). You'll have to use VS2002 or VS2003 for that.

ClickOnce is only supported for .NET 2.0 or later.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Depending on the features, you can probably write one yourself, however - a simple and small native bootstrapper to verify versions of all binaries and host CLR, and then handle `AssemblyResolve` events for all appdomains to download assemblies on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

.Net 1.1 isn't supported on VS 2010.  I don't even thing it was supported on VS 2005 or 2008.  I've always had a VS 2003 install in a VM for 1.1 maintenance stuff.

Comment: Strictly speaking, VS2010 is the first release which supports proper multi-targeting between various CLR versions. VS2008 let you chose .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5, but it was purely library set selector, not CLR version selector, since all those .NET versions used CLR 2.0. In VS2010, you can switch between targeting CLR 2.0 and CLR 4.0; 1.x is still not supported, however.

Comment: Is there a similar deployment tool(ClickOnce) for 1.1 framework app?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2008/08/22/working-with-net-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008-and-team-server.aspx) you can find a way to create your project in `.net 1.1` with VS 2008. And I think this is last version of the VS you can use to create your projects in `.net 1.1`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an application that uses e.g. an app pool using .Net 1.1,  compiling for .Net 2.0 simply isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You should just build your code with .NET 2.0, assuming there's some reason why you can't build it with .NET 3.5.